# Maven: copy only build jars and not build poms

Tags: java, maven

I have the following maven structure:

```
ParentProject
|-project-1
| |-src
| |-pom.xml
|-project-N
| |-src
| |-pom.xml
|-pom.xml
```

In parent project pom I use the following plugin for copying:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
    <execution>
        <id>copy</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                  <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                  <version>${project.version}</version>
                  <type>${project.packaging}</type>
                  <outputDirectory>/somepath/jars</outputDirectory>
                </artifactItem>
            </artifactItems>
        </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I use this plugin in parent project pom but not in project-1/N because I don't want to duplicate using this plugin and output directories (in some cases there can be one directory,in same cases several). The plugin works well. However, it also copies build parent project pom. How can I copy only project-1/N jars without parent project pom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can achieve it is by adding `skip` to true inside your parent:

```
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                <version>${project.version}</version>
                                <type>${project.packaging}</type>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And then switch it to false in your children:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
```

Comment: It seems to be the only solution.